# Invalid option, /FIC

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build OpenCV 3.2 using Visual studio 2017 community edition.
I am building without CUDA and all other options are kept as default.

I am getting this error while building:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   RC1103  invalid option, /FIC:/opencv/modules/videostab/src/precomp.hpp  opencv_videostab    C:\opencv\_build\modules\videostab\RC   1
```

It is also happens in other modules.

BTW during Cmake stage I got this warnings:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:81 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0020 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:85 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:94 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.
```

Comment: Looks like a space is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem too and found a solution.
I see you have posted this question on the OpenCV specific question board.
There is also one on the github issue board as well:

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9100
- http://answers.opencv.org/question/163349/invalid-option-fic/

I assume you have already used the solution posted over there but for the sake of completeness and anyone looking on Stackoverflow, here is the solution:

**The fast solution is to disable precompiled headers.** This will increase compilation time, but otherwise works fine:

[image: 1]